# We are expecting to or expecting for?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is more idiomatic with the verb 'expect' when it's followed by a noun, is it '**to**' or '**for**'?

> We are expecting **to** positive changes in future. 
>   We are expecting **for** positive changes in future.

Answer (score 1):

According to OALD ***expect something*** is correct.

> We are expecting positive changes in future.

Expect ***somebody/something to do something***

> We expect you to arrive by 8 o'clock

Answer (score 1):

Neither answer is correct. As Kshitij Singh said, "expect something" is the correct form in this case, so you would simply say "We are expecting positive changes in future."

"Expecting to" would be used when you are talking about what you expect yourself (or in this case, "we") to do, and would be connected to a verb to create the infinitive form ("to do", "to be"). For example, "We are expecting **to exhibit** (have) positive changes in future."

I can't think of a situation in which you would use "expecting for," and it sounds wrong to me. That doesn't mean it doesn't have meaning, however.